# TypeScript integration with Windows 8 Store apps

Tags: typescript, windows-store-apps

How would I use TypeScript in a Windows 8 Store app that's JavaScript-based?
I don't see any obvious way of doing this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Many of your questions are answered by the Encyclopedia example on the typescript site.

> http://www.typescriptlang.org/Samples/#Encyclopedia

Since TypeScript produces JavaScript Windows 8 and the Windows Store see them as a normal JavaScript based Windows Store application. The referenced example contains the modifications to the project file to build the `.ts` into `.js` automatically.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the TypeScript sample source code, they have full Win 8 app as an example:
http://typescript.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/d397c54a55db

Answer (score 1):

Although the Encyclopedia example is a representation of how TypeScript is used, there is not built in functionality to do so.  See the following link to see a complete walkthrough.

http://blog.tattoocoder.com/2012/10/typescript-for-windows-8-store-apps.html

Answer (score 1):

I recently build a project template to get started more quickly when building Store apps using TypeScript.

http://timmykokke.com/2014/01/store-app-typescript-project-template/

---

***Update:***
I've added the templates to http://sidewaffle.com/ which makes them a lot easier to use.

Comment: ... to enable "compile on safe" goto tools->options->text editor->typescript->project and turn on: automatically compile typescript files which are not part of a project